# Oven burning cabinetry underneath

Tags: oven

[image]

I removed an oven I placed in my property 5 years ago so see this. what could have caused this? its worrying me that it could have possibly caused a fire.

Comment: If you can find documentation, do they specify how much air space is required around it? Were there feet that got removed to make the unit fit?

Comment: It looks like something in the installation instructions must have been overlooked.

Comment: looks like it got hot. good thing fire need air, otherwise you'd be homeless.

Comment: Scary I think @Aloysius Defenstrate is spot on.+